# Content-Length header with HEAD requests?

Tags: http, rest, http-headers

The [http spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) says about the `HEAD` request:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request.

Should the response to a `HEAD` request contain a `Content-Length` header? Should it be the value which would be returned on a `GET` request, even if there is no response body? Or should the Content-Length be 0?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To me it looks like the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) is pretty specific:

> The Content-Length
>   entity-header field indicates the size of the entity-body, in decimal
>   number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, **in the case of the HEAD
>   method, the size of the entity-body that would have been sent had
>   the request been a GET**.

Comment: Interestingly enough, curl tells you that the body is missing... they may not "know" that the method is a HEAD when reading the reply and assume that the body is missing.

Comment: `curl --head` behaves better than `curl -X HEAD`.

Comment: wi don't get what it says, can you say it simpler?

Comment: @deadManN in `HEAD` request the `Content-Length` should be the same as it would have been in a `GET` request even though there's no actual body.

Comment: No longer relevant as the RFC 2616 was superseded by RFC 7230-7237. [Section 4.3.2 of RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) states *The server SHOULD send the same header fields in response to a HEAD request as it would have sent if the request had been a GET, **except that the payload header fields (Section 3.3) MAY be omitted***. Payload header fields defined in [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.3) are `Content-Length`, `Content-Range`, `Trailer` and `Transfer-Encoding`.

Answer (score 45):

[Section 14.13 of the HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) spec detailed the Content-Length header, and says this:

> Applications SHOULD use this field to
>   indicate the transfer-length of the
>   message-body, unless this is
>   prohibited by the rules in section
>   4.4.

The word 'SHOULD' has a [very specific meaning in RFCs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt):

> 3. SHOULD   This word, or the adjective "RECOMMENDED", mean that there may exist valid reasons in particular circumstances to ignore a particular item, but the full implications must be understood and carefully weighed before choosing a  different course.

So, you may not always see a Content-Length. Typically you might not see it for any content which is dynamically generated, since that might be too expensive to service an exploratory HEAD request. For example, a HEAD request to Apache for a static file *will* have a Content-Length, but a request for a PHP script may not.

For example, try this very website...

```
telnet stackoverflow.com 80

HEAD / HTTP/1.0
Host:stackoverflow.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 11 Jan 2016 10:58:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=c2eb4742a1e02d89cab0402220736c0bd1452509905; expires=Tue, 10-Jan-17 10:58:25 GMT; path=/; domain=.stackoverflow.com; HttpOnly
Cache-Control: public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=36
Expires: Mon, 11 Jan 2016 10:59:02 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 11 Jan 2016 10:58:02 GMT
Vary: *
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Guid: 487e80bc-3783-4cfd-d883-a3bc84253234
Set-Cookie: prov=8dc24306-c067-45eb-bf5d-cffa855c2b03; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 26303c15f8e035a2-LHR
```

No content-length there.

Comment: Notably, you also won't see `Content-Length` if it's a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` response.

Comment: @PaulDixon Could you shed some light on this thread? Thx. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290203/why-tomcat-return-different-headers-for-head-and-get-requests-to-my-restful-api

Comment: A `HEAD` request to google.com will now (11th of Jan 2016) return `Content-Length` as well.

Comment: ah well, that example had a good 6 year run! Have changed it to use stackoverflow.com :)

Comment: I think this example doesn't work anymore either; a `HEAD` request to stackoverflow.com now returns `Content-Length`.

Comment: So how do you actually force nginx to send the `Content-Length` header on `HEAD` requests? I need to do it in my application.

Comment: @PaulDixon +1 "Typically you might not see it for any content which is dynamically generated, since that might be too expensive to service an exploratory HEAD request."

Comment: No longer relevant as the RFC 2616 was superseded by RFC 7230-7237. [Section 4.3.2 of RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) states *The server SHOULD send the same header fields in response to a HEAD request as it would have sent if the request had been a GET, **except that the payload header fields (Section 3.3) MAY be omitted***. Payload header fields defined in [section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.3) are `Content-Length`, `Content-Range`, `Trailer` and `Transfer-Encoding`.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the  `Content-Length` of a `HEAD` response **SHOULD**, but not always does (see [@Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854842/content-length-header-with-head-requests/3854983#3854983)) include the `Content-Length` value of a `GET` response:

Stack Overflow does:

```
> telnet stackoverflow.com 80
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Length: 362245                           <--------
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 11:51:49 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 11:50:49 GMT
Vary: *
Date: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 11:50:49 GMT
```

Google doesn't:

```
> telnet www.google.com 80
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.ie


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 11:55:36 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: I think you're seeing the Content length of the error message you get for not using HTTP/1.0. If you send a proper 1.0 HEAD request, you do not get a content length. I tried this on a local apache instance also, and again, no content length was returned.

Comment: @Paul: Fixed my malformed request. I still get a `Content-Length` however, as I should. Even when using `HTTP/1.0`: http://i.imgur.com/iq9bm.jpg

Comment: Yes, the StackOverflow IIS servers do send it. Google doesn't though.

Comment: @Paul: Interesting. Google doesn't send it for 200 responses though. I get it for all the other return codes: 301, 302, 400, etc. +1 for finding the proper definition of "SHOULD" :)

Comment: How can you add the header in nginx?

Answer (score 8):

The [HTTP-spec at W3C](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) states:

> If the new field values indicate that the cached entity differs from the current entity (as would be indicated by a change in Content-Length, ...

Which (to me) means it should hold the "correct" value as you would in a `GET` response.

Answer (score 8):

Contra the accepted answer, [section 4.3.2 of RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.2) states:

> The server SHOULD send the same header fields in response to a HEAD request as it would have sent if the request had been a GET, except that the payload header fields (Section 3.3)

—which is to say, Content-Length, Content-Range, Trailer, and Transfer-Encoding—

> MAY be omitted.

This is [even weaker](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119#page-2) than the note on SHOULD in [Paul Dixon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3854983/27358):

> 5. MAY This word, or the adjective "OPTIONAL", mean that an item is
>    truly optional.  One vendor may choose to include the item because a
>    particular marketplace requires it or because the vendor feels that
>    it enhances the product while another vendor may omit the same item.

So the real answer is, you don't need to include Content-Length, but if you do, you should give the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

According to RFC 9110 - HTTP Semantics, the latest HTTP specification published in June 2022,

- [section 8.6, paragraph 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-8.6-6):

> A server **MAY** send a Content-Length header field in a response to a HEAD request (Section 9.3.2); a server **MUST NOT** send Content-Length in such a response unless its field value equals the decimal number of octets that would have been sent in the content of a response if the same request had used the GET method.

- [section 9.3.2, paragraph 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-9.3.2-2):

> The server **SHOULD** send the same header fields in response to a HEAD request as it would have sent if the request method had been GET. However, a server **MAY** omit header fields for which a value is determined only while generating the content. For example, some servers buffer a dynamic response to GET until a minimum amount of data is generated so that they can more efficiently delimit small responses or make late decisions with regard to content selection. Such a response to GET might contain Content-Length and Vary fields, for example, that are not generated within a HEAD response. These minor inconsistencies are considered preferable to generating and discarding the content for a HEAD request, since HEAD is usually requested for the sake of efficiency.