# Javascript check file size

Tags: javascript, filesize

Is it possible to keep checking with javascript if the filesize of a file on a webserver (e.g. http://www.mysite.com/myfile.js) is larger than 0 bytes and if so return a true or false value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need a simple ajax request and a Serverside endpoint that returns the size of a requested file... without that and by default it won't be possible

Comment: @sra: That's not [necessarily true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909641/javascript-check-file-size/7909914#7909914).

Answer (score 12):

Theoretically, you could use XHR to issue a HTTP `HEAD` request and check the `Content-Length` in the response headers.

A [`HEAD`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) request is identical to a regular `GET` request **except** the server MUST NOT return the actual content. In other words, the server replies with the headers it would have had you tried to `GET` the resource, but then stops and does not send the file.

However, [some severs respond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854842/content-length-header-with-head-requests/3854872#3854872) to a `HEAD` request with a `Content-Length` header of `0`, regardless of the actual size of the file. Others respond with the size of the file.

In order to accomplish this, you'll have to pray your server returns a file's actual size to a `HEAD` request.

If it does, [getting that value is easy](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/q9jp9/):

```
$.ajax('/myfile.js', {
    type: 'HEAD',
    success: function(d,r,xhr) {
       fileSize = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length');
    }
});
```

Note that JSFiddle's server always returns `0` when we `HEAD /`, even though `/` is `16916` bytes.

Also note what jQuery's [docs say](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) about the HTTP request type option:

> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

I just tested this Fiddle in IE 6-10, Firefox 3.6-7, Opera 9-11, and Chrome, and every single browser correctly issued the `HEAD` request, so I wouldn't worry about that vague incompatibility statement. Of more concern is how your server responds.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has no access to the filesystem (thankfully) so I'm afraid not.

Comment: +1 and there is no more to say if it runs in a browser. But I think it is worth to mention that this must not be correct if the JS runs outside of a browser cause the specification allows filesystem activity

Comment: Sorry I don't think I made it clear I want to check the filesize of a file on the web. I have edited the question, hopefully this is clearer and now and this is possible?

Comment: The comment from @sra to your actual question is the best answer in that case I think

Answer (score 0):

The idea given by josh3736 is great. Only the code example he gave, refused to work in my browser (Chrome 20, Firefox 13, IE 8, Opera 12), for the reason, that I don't know.

Here is the one, that worked perfectly in my case:

```
jQuery.ajax
({
    cache: false,
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'myfile.js',
    success: function(d,r,xhr){alert('File size is ' + xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length') + ' bytes.')},
    error: function(xhr, desc, er){alert('ERROR: "' + xhr.responseText + '"')}
});
```

I want also to notice, that Apache on-board XAMPP server works just fine with `HEAD` request, but of course, when run on localhost, such request is blocked by a browser with error message: "Origin localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" (example from Chrome).

Answer (score -2):

IE:
If you set the Ie 'Document Mode' to 'Standards' you can use the simple javascript 'size' method to get the uploaded file's size.

Set the Ie 'Document Mode' to 'Standards':

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

Than, use the 'size' javascript method to get the uploaded file's size:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uploadedFile = document.getElementById('imageUpload');
    var fileSize = uploadedFile.files[0].size;
    alert(fileSize); 
</script>
```

Other browsers:
On all the other browsers you can use the javascript 'size' method without any problems.

Comment: This will not work in IE9 or older, no matter what you meta tags you add.