# How to request only the content length of a file

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have a CDN with files, and I want to create a small tool that checks for the file existence there, based on a pre-defined files list.

I tried to use WebRequest, but it seems like it to download the file. I just want to get the content length without downloading it. (similar to curl -I )

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to make a HEAD request to get that information.

Quote from [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
>   be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
>   request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is
>   often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
>   and recent modification.
>
> The response to a HEAD request MAY be cacheable in the sense that the
>   information contained in the response MAY be used to update a
>   previously cached entity from that resource. If the new field values
>   indicate that the cached entity differs from the current entity (as
>   would be indicated by a change in Content-Length, Content-MD5, ETag or
>   Last-Modified), then the cache MUST treat the cache entry as stale.

From what I've read elsewhere, the content-length should be present in a HEAD response. But "should" doesn't necessarily mean it always is (see: [Content-Length header with HEAD requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854842/content-length-header-with-head-requests))