# force to download remote image immediately without HTML5

Tags: javascript, php, remoteobject

I trying to force to download a remote image (url with https protocol), I failed to attempts do it on client (cannot use HTML5, thanks to IE8), so I'm trying to use server side (php). 
The only way how to do it I found thanks [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14149927/730845), is using curl. Other way like readfile($file_url), always return an empty file. The problem with using curl - downloading starts after image is downloaded to server and it can take some time. Can we start loading directly from the source?

But if somebody know a way how to download an image on client side, that already on the page, it will be great!

Comment: The question isn't clear... do you perhaps mean *upload* to the server rather than download?

Comment: What do you mean by 'force'?

Comment: No, the main idea to allow user download image from the page (like "save image as..."), but image is situated on other server.

Comment: And the hoster of these remote images is OK with what you are trying to do – you have their explicit consent?

Comment: Yes, it is ok, it is our other server just some content should be shown on other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fopen('http://server/img.jpg')`, and `fread()`:

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/image.jpg", "rb");
while (!feof($handle)) {
  echo fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
```

plus headers.

Comment: $handle is empty after fopen, maybe some problems with php.ini, but "allow_url_fopen" is set to "On" state

Comment: one more thing that remote images url has https protocol

Comment: The default is not to verify peer, so certificate shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: but it was a problem, php_openssl was disabled, your solution works as well as readfile($file_url), when php_openssl is set to enabled. Thanks!